# Multidimensional Array Search by Multiple Keys given as Variable?

Tags: php, arrays, function, search, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array which has keys and key has values or have another array with keys and values so I want to search by keys but in input like 230 is user input
and it will go to 3 then 4 then 1 if result is a value but not an array it must print the value like
input = 230 result should be = "3-4-1"
so I need to str_split the number and search it 1 by 1 if first number is array then look for second kinda
edit1 = I found the way to split the key

```
//edit1
    $keys = "021";
       $keysSplit =str_split($keys, strlen($keys)/strlen($keys));
       echo $keys[0];
//edit 1 ends
    $arr = [0 => [0=>"1-1", 1 => "1-2" , 2=>"1-3", 3=>[0=>"1-4-1", 1 => "1-4-2" , 2=>"1-4-3"]],
        1 => [0=>"2-1", 1 => "2-2" , 2=>"2-3"],
        2 => [0=>"3-1", 1 => "3-2" , 2=>"3-3", 3=>[0 =>"3-4-1" , 1=> "3-4-2"]],
];

$keys = "021";
function searchByKey($array , $keys){
    $result = [];
$keys = "021";
$keys =str_split($keys, strlen($keys)/strlen($keys));
$key1 = $keys[0];
$key2 = $keys [1];
$key3 = $keys [2];
    foreach ($array as $key1 => $value){
        if (is_array($value)){
            $key1 = null;
          $key1 = $key2;
          $key2 = $key3;
        return searchByKey($value , $key1);    
        }
        else {
           $result=$value;
           echo $result;
        }
    }
}
$arr = searchByKey($arr, $keys);
```

The function only works as key and value given and it will print every key and value on the key it asked first so its not the thing I wanted to do could anyone help and explain?
Answer given by @Anggara I made it in to function ;

```
$input = "11";


function searchByNumber($array, $input){
$result = $array;    
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($input); $i++) {
    if (is_array($result)) {
        $result = $result[$input[$i]];
    } else {
        $result = "Does not exists";
        break;
    }
}
echo $result;
}


$arr = searchByNumber($arr, $input);
```

Comment: What does the variable '$value' has? Do you want , if key = 230 result will be 3-4-1?

Comment: I tried it by searching key and value just forget about the function might be to deep I have been trying things, and Yes if key = 230 result is 3-4-1 if exists. I also found the way to split the key I will edited the post @shirshak007

Comment: I edited the Function yet to be successful now it prints all results :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access char in string like accessing an array. For example:

```php
$input = "230";
// $input[0] is "2"
// $input[1] is "3"
// $input[2] is "0"
```

So my approach is to loop for each character in input key, and look for corresponding value in `$arr`. Each iteration will set found array element into variable `$result`. If the searched key does not exist (ex: "021"), print error message.

```php
<?php

$arr = [
    0 => [
        0 => "1-1",
        1 => "1-2",
        2 => "1-3",
        3 => [
            0 => "1-4-1",
            1 => "1-4-2",
            2 => "1-4-3"
        ]
    ],
    1 => [
        0 => "2-1",
        1 => "2-2",
        2 => "2-3"
    ],
    2 => [
        0 => "3-1",
        1 => "3-2",
        2 => "3-3",
        3 => [
            0 => "3-4-1",
            1 => "3-4-2"
        ]
    ],
];

$input = "230";

$result = $arr;

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($input); $i++) {
    if (is_array($result)) {
        $result = $result[$input[$i]];
    } else {
        $result = 'Can not traverse path';
        break;
    }
}

echo $result;
```

Comment: Thx , this is really helpful I will try to make it in to a function ^^

Answer (score 1):

After splitting the keys

```
for($i=0;$i<strlen($keys);$i++){
$arr = $arr[$keys[$i]];
}
if(is_array($arr)){
echo json_encode($arr);
}else{
echo $arr;
}
```

You need a loop, which will go through the keys one by one and assigning into the array.